# Como inserir o código Javascript dentro do meu HTML?

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer uma máscara para um formulário. Já tenho um código em JS pronto, mas não sei como inserir ele junto do HTML.

Comment: Como nosso amigo Bruno Ribeiro comentou. Esta correto mais veja oque sua aplicação javascript faz pois se for uma função automatizada tipo um texto que vai aparecer sera melhor botar seu código script dentro do <head></head> mais se for uma função no qual o usuário tenha que apertar ou passar o mouse coloque no final antes do fechamento da tag </body> para não deixar seu site lento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma tag script no header da sua pagina conforme exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script>
    document.getElementById('teste').value
</script>
```

e inserir o seu código javascript ou usar a tag:

```html
<script src="<caminho do seu arquivo .js>"></script>
```